# Event.DEACTIVATE does not work when Low battery alert has shown

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

After run my app , i escaped it with press HOME key. Then DEACTIVATE works well.

But When low battery alert showed DEACTIVATE does not work

How can i pause my app with DEACTIVATE when alert has shown.